# Plt.show() won't display anything while using jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

So I'm very new to python and just playing around with some graphs. The issue that I have is that plt.show doesn't display anything. plt.plot(x,y) displays the graph but without the x and y labels. I've tried to move things around but it doesn't seem to help.
Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('forcedecks-test-export-11_09_2022.csv')

specified = df.loc[df['Name'] == "Athlete 1"]

x = specified['Date']
y = specified["Peak Power / BM [W/kg] "]

plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Peak Power / BM [W/kg] ', fontsize=12)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Are you using Jupyter locally or are using a web environment like Google Colab? are you sure x and y have values inside them? Check with print(x), print(y)

Comment: Always best for a minimal reproducible example to share something we can access and run. Also a lot a of times the acting of making a shareable minimal reproducible example (MRE) helps you sort it out because you realize where the issue is. In a different vein...`plt.show()` isn't necessary most times with modern Jupyter now. Are you running the code you posted all in one cell? If not, how many? If plt.plot(x,y) displays the graph already then there'd be nothing for `plt.show()` to show. In yet another vein.. you seem to be asking multiple questions. You seem to really want the labels, right?

Comment: @Sup3rlum I'm using Google Colab. And both x and y has values in them.

Comment: @Wayne I'm using different cells for each line in the cell. Should I be using the same cell for the entire code? 
Yes, in this case I really want to display the labels

Comment: There's no reason to use the same cell for all the code; however, you should expect `plt.show()` to not display anything when run in a separate cell. The object in the plotting buffer (not the technical term but probably good enough for understanding now) has already been displayed. I suspect you may be using some old example code? Like I said,  modern Jupyter now looks more actively for matplotlib plotting objects in a cell and displays them. So `plot.show()` is not needed often. And in fact won't work again to show the plot again in a different cell. If you assign the plot to a variable ...

Comment: <continued> , then there are ways to call it again later in another fresh cell for displaying again. Or even subsequent modification and displaying. However, that isn't your need presently? You just want labels, right? Then given your title and most of your post, you should probably make a new Stackoverflow post addressing that topic. You've obtained the reasons behind the title of this post, "Plt.show() won't display anything while using jupyter notebook" already now.

Comment: Oops, I see you say you are using Google Colab. That is sort of different in some respects from modern Jupyter. (A fact you'll want to be aware of when posting.)  Since the Google colab-branded notebooks branched off a while back they unfortunately lack some things the modern Jupyter has now. However, in handling the plots it would seem they are similar enough so that in this case the explanation is similar. The problem was you separated the last to lines of your code when those should be in same cell, I suspect. (Or if it is showing a plot without needing `plt.show()`, you can leave it off.)

Comment: @MarkusFürst Writing every line in a different cell is not how a jupyter notebook is meant to be used. Have a look at the introductory example notebook on Google Colab to get a feel of how things are meant to be written. Your code is not displaying anything because you probably haven't ran all of the cells in order. Either write everything in one cell, or execute all of the cells in order from first to last.